# Defining a subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question I have to answer is as following in Swedish:

```
Hur många mängder X uppfyller {a, b, c} ⊆ X ⊆ {a, b, c, d, e}?
```

Loosely translated (I do not know mathematical terminology well in English):

```
How many sets X satisfy {a, b, c} ⊆ X ⊆ {a, b, c, d, e}?
```

I do not know how to solve this question. For instance, would `{{a,b}, a}` be two valid subsets of `{a, b, c, d, e}`?

Any insight into the main question is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No! $\{a,b\}\in \{\{a,b\},a\}$ but not belongs to $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$.

Comment: It should be: *How many sets* $X$ *satisfy* $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq X\subseteq\{a,b,c,d,e\}$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you Brian

Comment: In case it proves useful, here: http://www03.edu.fi/oppimateriaalit/matematiikansanakirja/ohjelma/matematik.htm is a dictionary that translates mathematical terms between English, Swedish, Finnish and Russian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly simple to list them. Sets have no duplicate elements by default. Sets do not include elements of different types or pairs. So you can't have pairs and elements. Pairs are generated through Cartesian products.

{a, b, c, d, e}

{a, b, c, d}

{a, b, c, e}

{a, b, c}

So the answer is 4.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want $\{a,b,c\}\subseteq X$ all you have to do is to choose the other possible elements to expand the smaller set $\{a,b,c\}$. You can do this choosing none or $d$ or $e$ or both $d,e$.